# TensorFlow Federated - Adapting existing keras model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I'm having trouble adapting an existing Keras model to work with [TenforFlow Federated](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated).

The existing model is a 1D convolutional autoencoder (details shown below)

**Existing Model:**

```
input_window = Input(shape=(window_length,1))

x = Conv1D(16, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(input_window)
x = MaxPooling1D(2, padding="same")(x)
x = Conv1D(1, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)

encoded = MaxPooling1D(2, padding="same")(x)
encoder = Model(input_window, encoded)

x = Conv1D(1, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(encoded)
x = UpSampling1D(2)(x)
x = Conv1D(16, 1, activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling1D(2)(x)

decoded = Conv1D(1, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_window, decoded)
```

Training data is passed as a `numpy.ndarray` of shape `(102, 48, 1)`.

Conceptually, this represents 102 days worth of data, each containg 48 values. I can provide an example of this if it would assist in answering.

My attempt to convert the model is shown below.

**Converted Model:**

```
def create_compiled_keras_model():

    input_window = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(window_length,1))

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(16, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(input_window)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(2, padding="same")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(1, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)

    encoded = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(2, padding="same")(x)
    encoder = tf.keras.Model(input_window, encoded)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(1, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(encoded)
    x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling1D(2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(16, 1, activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling1D(2)(x)

    decoded = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(1, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

    autoencoder = tf.keras.Model(input_window, decoded)
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='MSE')
    return autoencoder



sample_batch = train // numpy.ndarray of shape (102, 48, 1)


def model_fn():
    keras_model = create_compiled_keras_model()
    return tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model(keras_model, train)
```

This produces the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-397-9bed171c79be> in <module>
----> 1 model = model_fn()

<ipython-input-396-13bc1955a7f2> in model_fn()
      1 def model_fn():
      2     keras_model = create_compiled_keras_model()
----> 3     return tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model(keras_model, train)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/model_utils.py in from_compiled_keras_model(keras_model, dummy_batch)
    190     raise ValueError('`keras_model` must be compiled. Use from_keras_model() '
    191                      'instead.')
--> 192   return enhance(_TrainableKerasModel(keras_model, dummy_batch))
    193 
    194 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/model_utils.py in __init__(self, inner_model, dummy_batch)
    434     # until the model has been called on input. The work-around is to call
    435     # Model.test_on_batch() once before asking for metrics.
--> 436     inner_model.test_on_batch(**dummy_batch)
    437     # This must occur after test_on_batch()
    438     if len(inner_model.loss_functions) != 1:

TypeError: test_on_batch() argument after ** must be a mapping, not numpy.ndarray
```

So far I have been unable to resolve this.
Is this an issue relating to my model not being compiled correctly, or due to the way I'm passing data?

Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think you are trying to do something smiler to [this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated), however, the sample_batsh in your code just numpy array but in the example it is a map.

Comment: @Zaher88abd Thanks for your comment, is there any way that I can adapt this to use the numpy array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample batch should be something that can be passed to `batch_input` argument of [tff.learning.Model.forward_pass](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/Model#forward_pass).

For wrapped Keras models, this must be a dict with keys matching the arguments to [tf.keras.models.Model.test_on_batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Model#test_on_batch).

For this case, I think you may be able to simply wrap the sample batch in a dict with a single key of `x`:

```py
numpy_sample_batch = train // numpy.ndarray
sample_batch = {'x': numpy_sample_batch}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this seems to resolve the issue, but raises the following: `InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'conv1d_68_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?,?]
  [[{{node conv1d_68_target}}]]` Can you suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell without being able to reproduce (requires the full stack trace, the python code, and the dataset).

Almost looks like the Keras model is defined in a way that leads to dimension miss-match. If all the TFF wrapping is removed, does the Keras model work as expected?

Comment: Thanks for your help, is there any way that I could share a Jupyter notebook with you?

Comment: I'd first test if the Keras model is setup as expected (without any TFF). One way would be to try `model.fit(dataset)` on the object returned by `create_compiled_keras_model()`. If this doesn't work, I'd post a stack overflow question with the tensorflow or keras tags. If this does work, I'd open a new question for the tensorflow-federated tag with a minimal set of code to the reproduce the error. Sharing a notebook makes it harder for others who encounter a similar problem in the future to discover the solutions, so I'd encourage using SO.